# FreeRDP USB Redirection Not Working on Hyper-V?

Tags: hyper-v, rdp, usb, redirection

I  have compiled FreeRDP from the tip of the Master branch on (and for), an ARM v7 processor, (see cmake command line below).

It all seems to build correctly and the basic xfreerdp client works for a full remote desktop.

I cannot however determine how to get the USB redirection working with a remote virtual server running under Microsoft Hyper-V. I have tried many different command line switch options all without any success, (they also don't produce any error messages).

Reading the "USB Redirection" wiki entry it appears that there should also be a kernel module and service as well as the FreeRDP plugin. I haven't been able to locate any further information on these?

I have also provided a typical xfreerdp command line, (see below), that I have been using in my testing. The remote Hyper-V virtual server is a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine which has been tested and is fully functional with the Microsoft RDP client.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

---

**My CMAKE Command Line:**

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake -DVENDOR=CloudTerminal -DTARGET_ARCH=ARM -DMONOLITHIC_BUILD=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DWITH_SSE2=OFF -DWITH_NEON=ON -DARM_FP_ABI=hard -DWITH_GSTREAMER_0_10=ON -DWITH_JPEG=ON -DWITH_CUPS=ON -DWITH_PULSE=ON -DWITH_ALSA=ON -DWITH_CHANNELS=ON -DCHANNEL_URBDRC=ON .
```

---

**My XFREERDP Command Line:**

```
/usr/local/bin/xfreerdp /bpp:24 /f +compression -clipboard -fonts -aero -decorations -window-drag -menu-anims -themes -wallpaper /t:"Test Terminal" /cert-ignore /sec:tls /d:"DOMAIN" /v:"my.server.com" /usb:id,dev:0c45:6128
```

I've also tried other USB redirection switches such as:

/usb:id,dev:0c45:6128 /rfx

/dvc:urbdrc,id,dev:0c45:6128

/dvc:urbdrc,id,dev:0c45:6128 /rfx

/usb:id,dev:0c45:6128 /vc:usbrdr

etc...

---

**My XFREERDP Response:**

```
loading channel drdynvc

Unable to find a match for unix timezone: Etc/UTC

Loading Dynamic Virtual Channel urbdrc

VID: 0x0C45 PID: 0x6128

Regist Device: Vid: 0x0C45 Pid: 0x6128 InterfaceClass = 0xFF
```

Comment: How can this question possibly be "off-topic"?
Its precisely "on-topic" for the question asked!

Comment: My guess is the the combination of xFreeRDP, ARM v7 and USB Redirection smelled of ["home or development environment"](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) to people. Sometimes if you are working a corner-case in a [professional capacity](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4111/what-is-a-professional-capacity) you need to supply some context for why you are attempting to do something unusual. It also helps avoid the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) which is alarmingly common here.

Comment: Actually this is for a commercial product that we are developing and I am the lead engineer. We are investigating various candidate technologies for a thin client solution and this necessarily includes FreeRDP.